# как установить Центр приложений на Linux Муром ОС

Tags: linux

есть моноблок с RED OS release MUROM ( 7.2 (x86-64).
центр приложений вырезан. пароль суперюзера знаю. где достать/как установить центр приложений?

Comment: терминал доступен ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install software-center` по моему так должно быть

Comment: @MaximLensky доступен. говорит "apt-get: command not found"

Comment: Red OS вроде на основе Redhat, там по идее не apt-get, а yum

Comment: @insolor да возможно...

Comment: @insolor поставил yum. спасибо. не такой удобный как в Ubuntu но выбора нет как я понял